# Как в Sublime Text 3 при клике на класс сделать чтобы курсор перебрасывало на место его объявления?

Tags: sublime-text

Какой плагин для Sublime Text 3 позволяет делать так, чтобы во время редактирования CSS/
HTML файлов при клике на класс или айдишник, курсор сразу перебрасывало на место, где этот класс(айди) объявлен?

Answer (score 2):

Можно для этого установить плагин [Goto-CSS-Declaration](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Goto-CSS-Declaration). Потом просто в разметке ставите курсор на нужный класс и либо через контекстное меню выбираете *Go to CSS Declaration*. Вас перебросит на тот `CSS` файл в проекте, где описан этот класс. Либо можно горячие клавиши для него использовать.